# Extract only integer milliseconds from linux commandline ping

Tags: linux, command-line, extract, ping

I try to extract just integer number of milliseconds from continuous ping output in OpenWRT commandline. Example from `ping 8.8.8.8`

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=6 ttl=55 time=6.356 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: seq=7 ttl=55 time=6.520 ms
...
```

Desire output should looks like this:

```
6
6
...
```

Just integer (left part of number). Without fraction part and wihout dot.

I tried to cut output using pipes, firstly cutting equal signs `ping 8.8.8.8 | cut -d '=' -f 4` which works

```
6.389 ms
6.051 ms
...
```

Then cutting also dots to get integer only `ping 8.8.8.8 | cut -d "=" -f4 | cut -d '.' -f1` but then no output shows at all. I tried also using awk but when I use more than one pipe with those commands, there is no output. Could you show me how to do that.

Comment: `but then no output shows at all` buffering. Interest yourself in `stdbuf -oL`

Comment: Thank you, buffering was the clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output through perl (for example) and use a simple regex:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8 | perl -nle '/time=(\d+)/ && print $1'
```

This will print the integer part.

You could also round the milliseconds to the nearest integer with `printf`

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8 | perl -ne '/time=([\d\.]+) ms/ && printf "%.0f\n", $1'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses simple `sed` replacement trimming decimals and discarding all surrounding string.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | sed 's/.\+ time=\([0-9]\+\).\+/\1/'
```

Sample output:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
42
50
51
39
```

The following solution only trims the decimals. Same thing.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 | sed 's/\.[0-9]\+ ms$/ ms/'
```

Sample output:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=56 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=221 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=39 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=113 time=37 ms
```